# Active Light Stereopsis: 1 Camera + Projector Vs. 2 Camera + Projector

Tags: computer-vision, stereo-vision

What is the difference between using 1 Camera and a Projector and using 2 Cameras and a Projector for creating structure from motion?

Is it that if we use only 1 camera and a projector then we will have to move around the camera to create a stereo pair? But if we use 2 cameras and a projector then we can just get the stereo pairs at once? (1 image from 1 camera, and 1 from another)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the difference is not much, and mostly that having two cameras helps in overcoming the ambient effects of light that might otherwise pollute the scene, but otherwise perfectly interpretable results can be obtained from either of the two.